# dhclient can't get ip address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dhcp

I have two interfaces: eth0 and eth1. eth0 gets ip address upon bootup, but eth1 never gets ip address.
Here's what I get  with

> sudo dhclient eth1

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth1/08:00:27:99:8e:91
Sending on   LPF/eth1/08:00:27:99:8e:91
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x3b2d7ff3)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x3b2d7ff3)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0x3b2d7ff3)
```

Comment: sorry if this seems a bit of a silly question, but that log kinda suggests it, and it could save you much time: are you sure eth1 is connected (to a DHCP-enabled network) in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out this is due to my host machine doesn't automatically set the DHCP  for the HOST-Only network. one needs to manually configure that via virtualbox preference settings.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like eth1 is not wired to a network with a DHCP server attached to it.  You didn't say what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to share an Internet connection on eth0 with another network you probably want eth1 to have a static IP.