# Ubuntu can't get IP over DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dhcp, ubuntu-18.04

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm using netintall iso for that. It looks weird but during the installation process, the installer can't get an IP over DHCP. In the beginning, I thought that it is a problem with a network card but everything works fine under Slax live. I'm doing it on the physical host with Intel Atom core. How to fix that problem?

There is a similar topic but it has different hardware (VirtualBox) :( so given recipe doesn't applicable. [dhclient can't get ip address](https://superuser.com/questions/781839/dhclient-cant-get-ip-address)

The output of dhclient command looks like this:

**UBUNTU:**

```
~# dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp2s0/70:71:bc:6a:7b:ea
Sending on   LPF/enp2s0/70:71:bc:6a:7b:ea
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x289ae704)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x289ae704)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x289ae704)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x289ae704)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x289ae704)
```

**SLAX:**

```
root@slax:~# dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp2s0/70:71:bc:6a:7b:ea
Sending on   LPF/enp2s0/70:71:bc:6a:7b:ea
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of XXX.123.158.172 on enp2s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of XXX.XXX.158.172 from XXX.XXX.158.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 109.123.158.172 -- renewal in 33649 seconds.
root@slax:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason why the problem took place. It was simple but not obvious at the start.

The thing is the last Ubuntu versions (18.04, 19.10) don't support 32-bit architectures anymore. However, the **installer doesn't notify you that your architecture doesn't match 64-bit and keep trying to install OS**, which subsequently leads to a fault.

So, the recipe for me is to install 16.10 LTS.